# Regex replace using a substring of the regex result value

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been reading a ton of material and thought I had found my solution but no luck.  I need to find apostrophes contained in a name and then replace them with a double.  I am loading a file to an array and then looping through that, looking for the apostrophes.  The catch is that each row can have several apostrophes so that's why it's not a simple find and replace.

Here is a sample of the file:

```
   create(xxxxxxx)using(xxxxxxx)name('O'Doe, John')
   replace(xxxxxxx)instdata('ab 1234 ')
   create(xxxxxxx)using(xxxxxxx)name('Doe, O'Jane')
   replace(xxxxxxx)instdata('ab 5678 ')
```

There are other lines inbetween but they don't contain apostrophes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    $Pattern = "[A-Z]'[A-Z]"
    $user = gc C:\Temp\mfnewuser.ins
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $user.count; $i++) {
       if ($user[$i] -match $Pattern) {
       $user[$i] = [regex]::replace($strText, $Pattern.substring(2,1), "''")
       $user | out-file C:\Temp\mfnewuser.ins
       }
    }
```

I'm looking for a capital letter, followed by an apostrophe, followed by another capital.  Because of the other commas, I can't just do a global replace.  I know my pattern matching is working but I can't seem to manipulate it with the substring.  The substring looks at $Pattern as a string instead of the result of a regex.  If I can save the regex result to a variable, that would be great.  I think then the replace would be easy.

Tried this as well but no luck either:

```
    $Pattern = "[A-Z]'[A-Z]"
    $NewPattern = "[A-Z]''[A-Z]"
    $f = Get-Content C:\Temp\mfnewuser.ins
    $f = $f -replace $Pattern, $NewPattern
    $f | out-file C:\Temp\mfnewuser.ins
```

I may be approaching this all wrong and there is an easier way but I haven't seen anything yet.

**EDIT:**
Based on Bill_Stewarts example below, I've got this to work on the First Name but not yet the Last Name:

```
$Pattern = "[A-Z]'[A-Z]"
$user = gc C:\Temp\mfnewuser.ins
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $user.count; $i++) {
    if ($user[$i] -match $Pattern) {
        $user[$i] = $user[$i] -replace "(.*[A-Z])'([A-Z]+.*)", "`$1''`$2"
        $user | out-file C:\Temp\mfnewuser.ins
        }
    }
```

Comment: The regex is taylored to what forms you expect to see surrounding the apostrophe. Try one of @hwnd's regex's.

Comment: Looks like we got the same thing - ([A-Z])'([A-Z]) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
get-content "test.txt" | foreach-object {
  $_ -replace "([A-Z])'([A-Z])", "`$1''`$2"
}
```

Regular expressions can be grouped using ( ) and the -replace operator supports substring replacement ($1 and $2).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot.  I've seen the $1 and $2 references before but wasn't sure what those were for.  How do those work?

Comment: $0 means 'entire string that matched', $1 means 'first grouped subexpression', $2 means 'second grouped subexpression', and so forth.

Comment: Wouldn't `([A-Z])'([A-Z])` be sufficient?

Comment: That's enough for a match, but you need enough to do the replace.

Comment: OK, it kind of working.  It doubles-up the single-quote on the first name but not on the last: ('O'Last, O''First').  I'm still new to regex and don't yet understand all of the symbols used.

Comment: I've had to modify your example to work for me.  I've posted it above.

Comment: I forgot a bit about the specifics of the -replace operator. Try my amended answer.

Comment: Thanks Bill!  I had to assign the changes to a variable and then write the out-put to a file because I was getting file access errors but your suggestion worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line, with the following.

```
$user[$i] = $user[$i] -replace "([A-Z])'([A-Z])", "`$1`''`$2"
```

Or try one of the following. This should suffice.

```
get-content "mfnewuser.ins" | foreach-object {
  $_ -replace "([A-Z])'([A-Z])", "`$1`''`$2"
} | set-content "mfnewuser.ins"
```

...

```
get-content "mfnewuser.ins" | foreach-object {
  $_ -replace "([a-zA-Z', ]+)'([a-zA-Z', ]+)", "`$1`''`$2"
} | set-content "mfnewuser.ins"
```